# Rails after_save callback being called multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to inject an after_save callback via a mixin, but my rspec tests are telling me that the callback is being called twice when the `create` method is called.  Why is the method being called twice?

The following rspec test fails

```
it 'should call callback' do
  Product.any_instance.should_receive(:update_linkable_attachments).once
  Product.create(:name=>'abc')
end
```

The failure message is:

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
   (#<Product:0xb7db738>).update_linkable_attachments(any args)
       expected: 1 time
       received: 2 times
```

Here's the code

```
module MainModuleSupport
  def self.included(base)
    base.instance_eval("after_save :update_linkable_attachments")
  end 

  def update_linkable_attachments
    LinkedAttachment.delay.create_from_attachment self
  end
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MainModuleSupport
  ...

end
```

The Product class has other code, but does not have any other callbacks.

Comment: Rails version? I think there was an issue for this in a few releases.

Comment: LinkedAttachment might be triggering this on creation if it is related to product some way

Comment: I have created a clean Rails application 3.0.10. It works ok there. Can you please tell me what is `LinkedAttachment.delay.create_from_attachment`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

after_save is part of the transaction and therefore may be called more than once provided that you have other associated objects that need to be saved as well. In cases like this I typically move from the after_save callback to the after_commit callback which runs only after the transaction has completed.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but what if I want to make sure that all of the operations (the save and the callback ops) are committed together as a part of a single transaction?