# after_commit callback is being called several times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, callback

update:
Is it the case that a call to update_attributes gets it's own transaction?

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603448/rails-after-save-callback-being-called-multiple-times) question and for reasons in addition to that question, i've decided to go with after_commit as the proper hook. The problem is it's being called multiple (exactly three) times. The code is a little complex to explain, but basically there is a profile model that has

```
include Traits::Blobs::Holder
```

in holder.rb I have:

```
  module ClassMethods

    def belongs_to_blob(name, options = {})
      clazz = options[:class_name] ? options[:class_name].constantize : Blob
      foreign_key = options[:foreign_key] || :"#{name}_id"

      define_method "save_#{name}" do
        blob = self.send(name)
        if self.errors.any? && blob && blob.valid?
          after_transaction do
            blob.save!
            #self[foreign_key] = blob.id
            #save resume anyway
            self.update_attribute(foreign_key, blob.id)
          end
        end
      end
      after_validation "save_#{name}"

      belongs_to name, options

      accepts_nested_attributes_for name
    end

  end
```

finally in profile.rb itself I have:

```
after_commit :send_messages_after_registration!

protected

def send_messages_after_registration!
  Rails.logger.debug("ENTERED : send_messages_after_registration " + self.owner.email.to_s)
  if self.completed?
    Rails.logger.debug("completed? is true " + self.owner.email.to_s)
    JobSeekerNotifier.webinar_notification(self.owner.id).deliver
    Resque.enqueue_in(48.hours, TrackReminderWorker, self.owner.id)
  end
end
```

it appears that the method is entered 3 times. I've been trying to figure this out for a few days so any guidance you can provide will be appreciated.

controller code:

```
def create
  @user = Customer.new(params[:customer].merge(
    :source => cookies[:source]
  ))
  @user.require_password = true

  respond_to do |f|
    if @user.save
      promote_provisional_user(@user)  if cookies[:provisional_user_id]

      @user.profile.update_attributes(:firsttime => true, :last_job_title => params[:job_title]) unless params[:job_title].blank?

      if params[:resume]
        @user.profile.firsttime = true
        @user.profile.build_resume(:file => params[:resume])
        @user.profile.resume.save
        @user.profile.save
      end
    ...
end
```

Comment: Does Profile call belongs_to_blob ?

Comment: what does the calling code look like?

Comment: updated my question with the controller code

Comment: yes. profile has this association: `belongs_to_blob :resume`

Comment: here's a good question: when do association methods like belongs_to_blob get called in relation to transaction callbacks?

Comment: an even better question: how can I limit the call to :send_messages_after_registration to commits NOT associated with updates (i.e. only complete saves)?

Answer (score 4):

So it's happening 3 times because the profile is being saved 3 times: once when the user is saved (I assume that `User accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile`, once when you call `update_attributes(:first_time => true,...)` and once when you call save in the `if params[:resume]` block. Every save creates a new transaction (unless one is already in progress) you end up with multiple calls to `after_commit`

`after_commit` does take an `:on` option (which can take the values `:create`, `:update`, `:destroy`) so that you can limit it to new records. This would obviously fire on the first save so you wouldn't be able to see the profile's resumé and so on.

You could in addition wrap the entirety of those updates in a single transaction, in that case `after_commit` only gets called once, no matter how many saves take place inside the transaction by doing something like

```
User.transaction do
  if @user.save
    ...
  end
end
```

The transaction will get rolled back if an exception is raised (you can raise `ActiveRecord::Rollback` if you want to bail out)

Comment: could you explain a bit about how I'd `wrap the entirety of those updates in a single transaction` that sounds like the desired behavior. Thanks for the helpe!

Comment: that was a great idea but it still seems to send TWO emails.

Comment: then you;re probably calling save elsewhere. Log the callstack (call caller) or put a breakpoint in your callback to see where you are being called from