# is there a way to create an observer on a single field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, observer-pattern

update, in the end, the solution was to move this to the user model instead of profile. Notice that in profile, i have to check `obj.owner.email`. It seems that by the time that the profile is reached, obj.owner (user) has already been saved and none of the conditions pass.
This works in the other model.

what i'd like to do is limit the number of times emails are sent to when an email field in the users table goes from blank to a valid email. I''ve tried a couple of callback methods but those are [causing some problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750459/after-commit-callback-is-being-called-several-times).

I haven't found too much info on observers. I know you can do all the callback methods there but is there anyway to check on a single field?

profile.rb:

```
  before_save :send_messages_after_registration!, :if => lambda {|obj| obj.owner.email_changed? && (obj.owner.email_was.nil? || obj.owner.email_was.blank?) }


  def send_messages_after_registration!
    Rails.logger.debug("Entered send_messages_after_registration! with email : " + self.owner.email.to_s)
    after_transaction do
      unless self.owner.email.blank?
        Rails.logger.debug("email.blank? is false with email : " + self.owner.email.to_s)
        JobSeekerNotifier.webinar_notification(self.owner.id).deliver
        Resque.enqueue_in(48.hours, TrackReminderWorker, self.owner.id)
      end
    end
  end
```

I used before save because it's my understanding that .changed? will always be false if after_save or after_commit. Am I mistaken?

For a moment I thought it might be the after_transaction piece - but the log message is not even being written to the log file.

Comment: what event do you want to observe?

Comment: `when an email field in the users table goes from blank to a valid email`

Comment: before save, create or after...

Comment: after_save but only if that field went from blank to valid? == true

Comment: you won't be easily able to know what changed in your object `after_save`, why not `before_save`?

Comment: both those callbacks seem to be causing the dreaded `stack level too deep` issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
before_save :foo, :if => lambda {|obj| obj.field_name_changed? && obj.field_name == true }

def foo
 #whatever you need
end
```

Comment: i think this will work. but can you explain the lambda piece (aside from the fact that it's an anonymous function). I'm a little foggy as to why you have to use that here. Why not just put the conditional expression there instead?

Comment: it's just a matter of taste, I like to have my conditions in the lambda :)

Comment: hmm...ok. i'm having trouble reaching my `:foo` method. I just put the conditional in a (one line) named function and replaced everything after the `=>` with the name of the function: `:email_captured?`. i'm trying the lambda way now.

Comment: still doesn't seem to work. my `:foo` function never seems to get called.

Comment: drop a `debugger` within `lambda {|obj| obj.owner.email_changed? && (obj.owner.email_was.nil? || obj.owner.email_was.blank?) }`

Comment: just Rails.logger.debug()? or some callback specific debug tool?

Comment: it's a debug tool yep, the basic one in Rails. I fear one of the conditions isn't met, because your code is ok

Comment: well, here's what I did `before_save :send_messages_after_registration!, :if => lambda {|obj| Rails.logger.debug("profile: email changed? " + obj.owner.email_changed?.to_s); Rails.logger.debug("profile: email nil? " + obj.owner.email_was.nil?.to_s); Rails.logger.debug("profile: email blank? " + obj.owner.email_was.blank?.to_s); obj.owner.email_changed? && (obj.owner.email_was.nil? || obj.owner.email_was.blank?) }` none of the log messages show up in my log file.

Comment: What orm do you use? Your code is avlid so the problem lies elsewhere. Does the object pass validation?

Answer (score 0):

you might want to look at acts_as_versioned (https://github.com/technoweenie/acts_as_versioned) or acts_as_audited (https://github.com/collectiveidea/acts_as_audited) this way you know previous email address and will decided whether to send email or not in observer code.